# Qt Creator Error: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake, qt-creator

I have installed opencv, qt, qt creator, cmake on **ubuntu 15.10** through VMware on windows.

The [opencv](https://github.com/opencv/opencv) is **installed** in this directory: `/home/majidalaeinia/opencv/`

The [project repository](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv) is cloned in this directory: `/home/majidalaeinia/Desktop/imgwarp-opencv/`

I want to run [the project](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv) through its [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt) in qt creator and when I press **Build now** on qt creator, I get the following errors:

```
error: cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs
error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Where is the problem and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you have the directory where `libopencv_imgcodecs.so` exists in your library CMakeLists.txt's library path? Do you find it in CMake with `find_package()`?

Comment: No , I do not have this file. How should I link the opencv to the project? Please note that they are in different directories.

Comment: Different folders is fine as long as you tell CMake how to find it. Are you saying that you do not have that library you want to link against (it could be a `.a` instead of a `.so` or have an extension like `.so.1` or even `.so.2.55.3` (numbers chosen at semi-random))?

Comment: I tried these commands: `find /home/majidalaeinia/opencv -type f -name "libopencv_imgcodecs"` and `find /home/majidalaeinia/Desktop/imgwarp-opencv -type f -name "libopencv_imgcodecs"`, found nothing.

Comment: You need to add a star in there: `find ~/opencv -name "libopencv*"` should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, thank you, found it here: `/home/majidalaeinia/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_imgcodecs.so.4.1`. What should I do next?

Comment: How are you telling CMake about your library -- by using `FIND_PACKAGE` or by manually adding it to a link flags? If the former, add the values returned from the call to your build / link commands. If the latter, add the path to your lib (sans the filename) there.

Comment: I really don't know how to do that. I just know it is related to the `FIND_PACKAGE`, but do not know what to put there, I even tried directories and some files there but got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ Majid Alaeinia,I uploaded the repository and went through the code. if you go inside the `demo` folder and you change the present `CMakeLists.txt` file with the one I provided below it should compile (It does compile on mine with the provided changes):

```
project(demo)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)
find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Widgets Core)
FIND_PACKAGE( OpenCV REQUIRED )

include_directories(${QT_INCLUDES} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})

set(demo_SRCS main.cpp projfile.cpp deformwin.cpp myimage.cpp singlephotoview.cpp pointspaint.cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

#qt5_automoc(${demo_SRCS})

QT5_WRAP_CPP(QOBJ_CPP ${demo_SRCS})
qt5_wrap_ui(helloworld_FORMS_HEADERS deformwin.ui)
add_executable(demo ${demo_SRCS} ${helloworld_FORMS_HEADERS})
target_link_libraries(demo ${QT_QTCORE_LIBRARY} ${QT_QTGUI_LIBRARY} imgwarp-lib opencv_core opencv_imgproc opencv_imgcodecs)
```

The code in the repository is an old code and still carries `Qt4` as main wrappers. I think you probably have `Qt5` installed on your computer and in fact the code I provided it will work for `Qt5`. Use it as a guideline for the other `CMakeLists.txt` file present inside `src` folder and change accordingly.

`CMake` will compile but because it was used `Qt4` you need to figure out the most important modules to add, for example the new standard for including `QtGui/QApplication` is usually substituted by `QtWidgets/QApplication`

I also wanted to leave my previous answer in case you need a starting point or a initial template. I hope this clarifies a bit more and can get you move forward for your project.

Answer (score 2):

@ Majid Alaeinia, from the `CMakeLists.txt` file you posted it is not specified how `CMAKE` should find the libraries requested from your project. Also there are no `target_link_libraries` declared so `CMAKE` does not know where to link them. Hopefully the following small example template should be helpful for your project:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.1)
project(yourProject)

find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
find_package( Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Sql )

### this is for c++11
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)

### QT stuff if you want a GUI
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)  # autogenerate qt gui features
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)  # used for QT resource Files (if you need)

## Additional operation...

# From here you are specifically linking all OpenCV libraries and executables
### Add executables
add_executable(yourExecutable main/main.cpp ui/res/res.qrc ${SRCS} ${UI_HDRS} ${UI_SRCS})
target_link_libraries (yourProject example Qt5::Widgets ${OpenCV_LIBS}  Qt5::Sql)

### Add Library
add_library(yourProject_lib SHARED ${SRCS} ${UI_HDRS})
target_link_libraries (yourProject_lib example Qt5::Widgets ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Comment: Thanks, this might help but I still do not know how to do that, because there are other `CMakeLists.txt` in other directories too. Check the [repository](https://github.com/cxcxcxcx/imgwarp-opencv) please.