# How to properly set an API call in QML using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: c++, json, qt, xmlhttprequest, qml

I am building a small weather API as exercise to use `QML` and properly operate an API call using [OpenWeather](https://openweathermap.org/current) and you can see there a typical API response.

**The problem** I am having is that I can't get the API call to work. After setting a minimal example with some cities that you can see below, right next to the city it should appear the symbol of the weather, but it does not happen. The list of the icon can be found [here](https://openweathermap.org/weather-conditions). Source code of the MVE can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/ERaggi/qmlweatherapp/src/master/) for completeness.

The error from the compiler: `qrc:/main.qml:282: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: Parse error`

**This is what is happening**

[image: current]

**This is what is expected**

[image: expected]

Typical API `JSON` response can be found both [here](https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02) and below:

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -122.08,
    "lat": 37.39
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 800,
      "main": "Clear",
      "description": "clear sky",
      "icon": "01d"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 282.55,
    "feels_like": 281.86,
    "temp_min": 280.37,
    "temp_max": 284.26,
    "pressure": 1023,
    "humidity": 100
  },
  "visibility": 16093,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.5,
    "deg": 350
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 1
  },
  "dt": 1560350645,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 5122,
    "message": 0.0139,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1560343627,
    "sunset": 1560396563
  },
  "timezone": -25200,
  "id": 420006353,
  "name": "Mountain View",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Below a snippet of code related to the API call:

**main.qml**

```
// Create the API getcondition to get JSON data of weather
function getCondition(location, index) {
    var res
    var url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={city id}&appid={your api key}"
    var doc = new XMLHttpRequest()
    // parse JSON data and put code result into codeList
    doc.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(doc.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            res = doc.responseText
            // parse data
            var obj = JSON.parse(res)  // <-- Error Here
            if(typeof(obj) == 'object') {
                if(obj.hasOwnProperty('query')) {
                    var ch = onj.query.results.channel
                    var item = ch.item
                    codeList[index] = item.condition["code"]
                }
            }
        }
    }
    doc.open('GET', url, true)
    doc.send()
}
```

In order to solve this problem I consulted several sources, first of all : [official documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-qmlglobalobject.html#xmlhttprequest) and the related function. I believe it is correctly set, but I added the reference for completeness.
Also I came across [this one](https://blog.felgo.com/cross-platform-app-development/access-rest-services-qt-felgo-weather-service-example-app-open-source) which explained how to simply apply `XMLHttpRequest`.
Also I dug more into the problem to find a solution and also consulted [this one](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtdoc-demos-tweetsearch-example.html) which also explained how to apply the `JSON` parsing function. But still something is not correct.

Thanks for pointing in the right direction for solving this problem.

Comment: no one will download the source, install icons and whatever else. you have to provide [mcve] instead. if the site you get the JSON from is not accessible please provide the response (doc.responseText). as for the question - the error is pretty clear, the JSON you receive is incorrect, that's all

Comment: @folibis, thanks for stopping by and read the question, your time is very much appreciated. The code is publicly available for being downloaded and tested by anyone who would want to give it a try. The source code is minimal enough: is a window with buttons. I personally downloaded source code and provided [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632996/qt-creator-error-cannot-find-lopencv-imgcodecs/55660716#55660716) for other users to try to help. I found and posted a solution to my question below hoping that would be useful for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the answer to my question. I was not reading properly the `JSON` file and after console logging the problem the solution is below. code was correct from beginning, only the response needed to be reviewed properly and in great detail being the `JSON` response a bit confusing:

```
function getCondition() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest()
    request.open('GET', 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid=key', true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (request.status && request.status === 200) {
                console.log("response", request.responseText)
                var result = JSON.parse(request.responseText)
            } else {
                console.log("HTTP:", request.status, request.statusText)
            }
        }
    }
    request.send()
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

In your code, your url shows this: `"api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?id={city id}&appid={your api key}"`. You need to replace `{city id}` and `{your api key}` with real values.

You can solve it by providing an actual city ID and API key in your request URL

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/26495784)

Comment: Ah, thanks for the links. Forgive my SO naivete. I read on one of them that it's perfectly fine to say "I'm not sure what the cause of your problem is, but if it's X, you can solve it by doing Y." So maybe my answer would be better if I wrote it as: "I'm not sure if you're receiving an error from the server, but if so, you can solve it by providing an actual city ID and API key in your request URL".

Comment: The fact that you explicitly said "I don't have the reputation points to add a comment" is a severe red flag that the answer shouldn't be an answer, and lead me to post that automatic comment. My personal opinion is that the thing being described here is sufficiently trivial that it's unlikely to actually be the problem (of course the user wouldn't publically post their API key), so it better as a comment (something like "Did you remember to replace {city id} and {your api key} with real values?") if it needs to be mentioned at all.

Comment: @JarMan, thank you very much for stopping by and reading the question, and for trying to answer. Your time and effort is very appreciated. The `{city id}` and `{your api key}` is a statement that I inserted on purpose not to share the real key, but that was not the error. I found a solution yesterday afternoon and I am going to post it shortly so that other users can benefit from this question.